# Open Refine: Split column using regular expressions that include 2 or more names joined by "And"

Tags: regex, split, openrefine

How do I split columns using regular expressions that include 2 or more names joined by "And". For example, "Jonathan And Betty" should be split into two separate columns containing Jonathan, Betty. However, I do not want to split names as Ander, Andrew or Andy.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the column menu, choose the menu item « Split into several columns... »

[image: menu item « Split into several columns... »]

Enter this Regex separator: `\s+(?i)and\s+`
(It will catch all variations of case, making it case insensitive.)

[image: Dialog for the Split command.]

And here's your end result:

[image]

Regards,
Antoine

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact edge cases, you should be able to do it using something like "(\w*)( And )(\w*)" for the match and "$1,$2" for the substitution. It won't match names Ander because, for example, there's no space between 'And' and 'er'. But it will match the positive case you gave, and the first group match will be separated by the second group match by a comma as specified in the substitution.

Here's a fiddle example of this in Javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/s78wp5fz/

```
const tests = ["Jonathon And Sue", "Anders and Mitchandre"];
const out = tests.map((test) => test.replace(/(\w*) [Aa]nd (\w*)/,'$1,$2'))
console.log(out);
```